# Handling several nested interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a set of nested classes like follows:

```
class A_Class
{
     ...
}

class B_Class
{
    ...
    List<A_Class> A_List
}
class C_Class
{
    ...
    List<B_Class> B_List
    B_Class Selected_B
}
class D_Class
{
    ...
    List<C_Class> C_List
}
```

These contain some pretty complex lambda logic, however there are only a few needed inputs and outputs on each class. I now have a need for a different implementation of this object, without all the complex logic, only the fields so the expected outputs can be set.

However I also have some methods that read the outputs of the above classes, which will also need to be able to read from the new implementation.

So I have interfaces as follows:

```
interface A_Interface
{
     ...
}

interface B_Interface
{
    ...
    List<A_Interface> A_List
}
interface C_Interface
{
    ...
    List<B_Interface> B_List
    B_Interface Selected_B
}
interface D_Interface
{
    ...
    List<C_Interface> C_List
}
```

And change above the classes to implement these interfaces

```
class A_Class : A_Interface
{
     ...
}

class B_Class : B_Interface
{
    ...
    List<A_Class> A_List
}
class C_Class : C_Interface
{
    ...
    List<B_Class> B_List
    B_Class Selected_B
}
class D_Class : D_Interface
{
    ...
    List<C_Class> C_List
}
```

This gives issues with return types, and sadly as the original developer of these classes has the implementation of the classes coupled with each other I cant change for example `List<B_Class> B_List` into `List<B_Interface> B_List` without exposing in that interface a large number of fields specific to the original implementation.

I've attempted a solution with generics such that:

```
interface Interface_D<Type_C, Type_B, Type_A> where Type_C : Interface_C<Type_B, Type_A> where Type_B : Interface_B<TypeA> where TypeA : Interface_A
{
    List<Type_C> C_List
}
interface Interface_C<Type_B, Type_A> where Type_B : Interface_B<TypeA> where TypeA : Interface_A
{
    List<Type_B> B_List
    Type_B Selected_B
}
interface Interface_B<Type_A> where Type_A : Interface_A
{
    List<Type_A> A_List
}

class A_Class : Interface_A {...}
class B_Class : Interface_B<A_Class> {...}
class C_Class : Interface_C<B_Class,A_Class> {...}
class A_Class : Interface_D<C_Class,B_Class,A_Class> {...}
```

This works in that it allows me to compile. But when consuming the top level class (D_Class) I have to declare it like:

```
Interface_D<Interface_C<Interface_B<Interface_A>, Interface_A>, Interface_B<Interface_A>, Interface_A> Obj;
```

I can get around this with another interface that extends this mess of interfaces/types.

```
Interface_DBase : Interface_D<Interface_C<Interface_B<Interface_A>, Interface_A>, Interface_B<Interface_A>, Interface_A>
```

However I still can't cast an instance of `D_Class<C_Class,B_Class,A_Class>` (the existing implementation) into a `Interface_DBase` in order to consume it.

So is there a way to do this cast? Or even better avoid having all these nested type arguments in interfaces entirely? I'm hoping I have an XY problem on my hands, and there is a proper way to implement this which I haven't stumbled over.

Comment: Not sure about fixing your type mess, don't think that's avoidable.  But to make your consumption code a bit more readable, at the top of your class you can add a type alias `using Interface_DBase = Interface_D<Interface_C<Interface_B<Interface_A>, Interface_A>, Interface_B<Interface_A>, Interface_A>`  then your method signatures could take `Interface_DBase`

Comment: _"I'm hoping I have an XY problem on my hands"_ -- maybe. But you've loaded up your question with code, and left out context. You should first come up with an example that does not require so many types (surely the issue can be demonstrated with fewer), and provide the necessary context to understand better the overall problem. ...

Comment: ... I will say: at first blush, you seem to have presented the all-too-common generic type variance question, just obfuscated with a lot more code than is usually seen in such questions. You get compiler errors, because what you're attempting isn't safe. E.g. if you could implement `List<A_Interface> A_List` with a `List<A_Class> A_List`, then you could hand the interface to some other code, which could then add some implementation of `A_Interface` to the list that isn't `A_Class`. Which of course is illegal.